# nginx shows vhost instead of default root

Tags: nginx, configuration

I just installed ngninx on my dev machine.

- It automatically migrated my vhosts from lighttpd (very comfy!), I only had to adjust the TLDs (it only took `\.dev`, I changed that to `\.(dev|test|local)`.
- and bound itself to port 81; after removing lighttpd, I changed the ports in `/etc/nginx/sites-available` to 80.

But when I call `http://<ip-adress>/` in the browser, I get the index page of one of my vhosts instead of the default DOCUMENT_ROOT (`/var/www/`).

I touched `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`, changed the port number and uncommented the PHP block. 
current contents (comments stripped):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www;
    index.php index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Half of the vhosts had self-references in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`, I replaced them with symlinks to `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and added a symlink for `default`; all my vhosts can now be accessed, but calling the IP address still routes to the same vhost instead of `/var/www`.
That vhost file is neither alphabetically first nor considering  the mtime, but it is when I list the directory unsorted (`ls -f`), it even comes before `..`.

How do I get nginx to deliver `/var/www/` instead of `/var/www/vhost/`?

---

update: After a few clicks on my primary vhost, switching to https and back, it changed:
`http://www.vhost1.test` now routes to `/var/www`, but the other vhosts seem to work correctly.

---

update: I tried to solve the problem by uncommenting the `server` block in `nginx.conv` (pointing to `/var/www`) and linking `sites-enabled/default` to `sites-available/vhost1`. The latter resulted in both the ip-address and vhost1 getting routed to another vhost. The other vhosts are still working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got it:
`sites-available/vhost1` only had `listen 443 ssl;`; `listen 80;` was missing
(because `listen 80 default_server` caused a "duplicate default server" error),
so calling the domain via port 80 fell back to the default server.